# How can I mitigate the error in Python Dictionary?

Tags: python

How do I access to visibilities?
I am trying like this: `dev1['data']['results :visibilites ']`

```
    dev1 = {
     "status": "OK",
     "data": {
     "results": [
       {
        "tradeRelCode": "ZT55",
        "customerCode": "ZC0",
        "customerName": "XYZ",
        "tier": "null1",
        "visibilites": [
          {
            "code": "ZS0004207",
            "name": "Aabc Systems Co.,Ltd",
            "siteVisibilityMap": {
            },
            "customerRef": "null1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
     "pageNumber": 3,
     "limit": 1,
     "total": 186
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please read the docs about data structures. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dev1['data']['results'][0]['visibilites']`. 
It will contain a list of one dictionary.

To access this dictionary directly, use `dev1['data']['results'][0]['visibilites'][0]`

---

`dev['data']` represents a dictionary that has for key `results`.

You can access the item associated to `results` key (a list) using `(dev1['data'])['results']`.

To access the only member of this list, you use `((dev1['data'])['results'])[0]`.
This gives you a dictionary that has `tradeRelCode`, `customerCode`, `customerName`, `tier` and `visibilites` keys.

To access the item associated to  `visibilites` key (a list), you have tu use `(((dev1['data'])['results'])[0])['visibilites']`.

To finally access the only dictionary contained in this list, you have tu use `((((dev1['data'])['results'])[0])['visibilites'])[0]`.

Parenthesis are here to show that python dig into each dictionary or list in order from left to right (python does not mind the parenthesis in the code, you can keep them if it is clearer for you.)

Comment: already tried with the same but getting following error : list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I did not notice that `results` is a list too. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It solves my problem, Can you please explain the code ?

Comment: I added more detail, do not hesitate to tell me if it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your data structure use path

```
dev1['data']['results'][0]['visibilites']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
dev1['data']['results'][0]['visibilites']
```

*Reason:*

This is a list -> `dev1['data']['results']`

So, access this -> `dev1['data']['results'][0]`

and then you obtain this ->

```
{'tradeRelCode': 'ZT55',
 'customerCode': 'ZC0',
 'customerName': 'XYZ',
 'tier': 'null1',
 'visibilites': [{'code': 'ZS0004207',
   'name': 'Aabc Systems Co.,Ltd',
   'siteVisibilityMap': {},
   'customerRef': 'null1'}]}
```

and then you can have -> `dev1['data']['results'][0]['visibilites']`

which results in ->

```
[{'code': 'ZS0004207',
  'name': 'Aabc Systems Co.,Ltd',
  'siteVisibilityMap': {},
  'customerRef': 'null1'}]
```

which is a `list` and you can index the first element which is another dictionary